# Listview inside of SlidingUpPanel in flutter

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter project, I used SlidingUpPanel to show some data on the map. There are some information shown on the map inside the panel and 2 separate listviews in DefaultTabController underneath.

However, while scrolling on the listview, it also moves the panel itself. When I searched to solve this problem, it is written that PanelController and ScrollController should be used in SlidingUpPanel. However, 2 separate scrolls should be used depending on a single panel.

In this case, it gives "ScrollController attached to multiple scroll views" error. If I make 2 separate ScrollController, this time it does not work as desired because it is not connected to anywhere under SlidingUpPanel.

What can I do to solve this situation?

Panel Package is https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel2

```
    late ScrollController scrollController;
    late PanelController panelController;

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabSelection);
     scrollController = ScrollController();
    panelController = PanelController();
  }

  SlidingUpPanel _slidingUpPanel(BuildContext context) {
    return SlidingUpPanel(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      maxHeight: context.dynamicHeight(0.75),
      minHeight: context.dynamicHeight(0.3),
      backdropEnabled: true,
      parallaxEnabled: true,
      parallaxOffset: .5,
      controller: panelController,
      scrollController: scrollController,
      panelBuilder: () => DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const Icon(
              Icons.drag_handle,
            ),
            mapInfo(),
            _buildTabBar(), // contains TabBar and 2 pill button
            _tabViews(), 
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: googleMapScreen(),
    );
  }

  void _handleTabSelection() {
    setState(() {});
  }

Expanded _tabViews() {
    return Expanded(
      child: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          PointScreen(
            panelController: panelController,
            scrollController: scrollController,
          ),
          TimesScreen(
            panelController: panelController,
            scrollController: scrollController,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

In Both TimesScreen and Points screen,

```
        return ListView.builder(
        controller: widget.scrollController,
        physics: PanelScrollPhysics(controller: widget.panelController!),
```